# Git to move head back to latest commit

Tags: git, commit

I have used Git to view some older files using the `git checkout <hash>` command.

However, now I want to move the head back to the latest commit without saving the changes I did at the older files.

Could you help on how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+checkout

Comment: `git checkout -f master` (or whatever branch you want).

Answer (score 1):

You did not explain you needs, so I am trying to guess...

Try with:

```sh
git reset --soft HEAD~1

# or

git reset --soft <COMMIT_ID>
```

Rembember `--soft` leave changes as uncommitted in order to inspect without loosing them.

Replace it with `--hard` if you need to discard them.